# Unable to open HTML file from assets folder on button click

Tags: android

html page doesn't open after clicking the button. I need html page to be opened in web view on button click in another activity. Pasting both the java files:

prerequisites.java:

```
public class Prerequisites extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    WebView wv;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_prerequisites);


    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId()==R.id.bowls)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, bowls.class);
            Button btbowls=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bowls);

            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }


}
```

bowls.java:

```
public class bowls extends AppCompatActivity  {
    WebView wv;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bowls);

        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.bowlswebview);
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/bowls.html");
    }


    }
```

Comment: Post your stacktrace.

Comment: U mean Log cat?

Comment: Yes,you need to post the exception from logcat

Comment: post your bowls.class code

Comment: you cut wrong picec of your stacktrace image. Never show images of stacktrace, show the text.

Comment: post your bowls.class and make sure that your bowls.class is added in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: please view my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Elackya

if you add your web view in activity_prerequisites then the below code will work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public WebView wv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = findViewById(R.id.button2);

    final String webLink = getIntent().getStringExtra("weblink");
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    wv.loadUrl(webLink);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            intent.setAction("weblink");
            intent.putExtra("weblink", "file:///android_asset/hello.html");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
}
```

If you add your web view in another activity, then the source code of the second activity is like below

```
public class bowls extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    WebView ww = findViewById(R.id.webView2);
    Intent web = getIntent();
    String url = web.getStringExtra("weblink");
    ww.loadUrl(url);

}
}
```

Your main activity class should be like 
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = findViewById(R.id.button2);
       btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),bowls.class);
            intent.setAction("weblink");
            intent.putExtra("weblink", "file:///android_asset/hello.html");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
}
```

And AndroidManifest.xml should include the activity bowls

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
   android:name=".bowls"
   android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks. But what I need is , when I click a button from prerequisites.java file, I need the html file to be opened in another activity (i.e.) bowls.java

Comment: Please see the above updated answer. If it's not as per your requirement, please share your activity_prerequisites xml and bolws.xml

Comment: Great it worked. I have been struggling for a long time.. thanks a lot for your clear explanation

Answer (score 0):

It... it's just not how it work, putExtra is used to pass info to another activity, not to do what you're trying to do, it crashed because your intent make no sense, and intent is used as a package to send to another activity, there is also no intent to get

anyway, here's the fixed code

```
public class Prerequisites extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

WebView wv;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prerequisites);
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.bowlswebview);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.bowls:
            wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/bowls.html");
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where do I add the file path/url?

Comment: from which class are you getting the intent ?

Comment: @Elackya I fixed the code to include the url of the file to load to webview.

Comment: did it crash or something else? I noticed that I forgot to remove this line  


String webLink = getIntent().getStringExtra("weblink");

A few min ago, if it still in your code, remove it too.

Comment: It didn't crash.. on clicking that button, no actions happened. int stays on the same screen

Comment: could you post the content of activity_prerequisites.xml?